# Securing API in jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, api, security

I have an app landing page. Visitors enter their phone number and I send a link to their phone.

I pass that number to my API with jQuery (Ajax). Now anyone can see that URL. So, anyone can grab that URL and send many requests. How can I protect it?

I have already implemented `CSRF Token`. Now I'm doing it with PHP. Generating a a token and storing it on `session`.

But there is a also a problem. If someone loads the landing page, they get that `token` and after that they can use that token to send request. I have tested this with Postman.

I can clear that CSRF Token after one request. But I don't want to do that. As they may require to send this link to other numbers.

Now what I want to do is, make that URL `private`, at least make hard to find and only requests made from my website should be accepted not from other tools.

Please help!

Comment: A private URL, interesting. Let me know how that works out for you.

Comment: CSRF tokens should have an expiration date within them to avoid such an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to protect yourself from is brute force attack. The most common and quick way to prevent this is using CAPTCHAs. You can use [Google Recaptcha](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/v3beta.html).

Besides, the app server should always validate request data, make sure you're using POST Method and sanitize data to prevent SQL Injection or hack attempts.

Comment: Thank you! I have implemented recaptcha and it works for me.